# coub.com video - forcing fullscreen with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, video, fullscreen

i am testing coub(dot)com which allows you to create short looped videos and has pretty good embedding support. However. I made a draft of a site

the videos is in the background, on top is a white div with some text.

i would like to know how I can force the video to stretch fill the browser window.

I wrote to coub and they said it can be done with javascript. they have done it with their homepage coub(dot)com (see at the login/signup page). I can't seem to decipher how they did it.

any thoughts?

this is what I have:

```
<html class='no-js' lang='en'>
<head>
    <script src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
html, body {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    }
    body {
    background:none;
    color:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="coubVideo" src="http://coub.com/embed/73x2s
?muted=true&
autostart=true&
noControls=true&
noHDControl=true&
noSiteButtons=true&
originalSize=false&
hideTopBar=true&
startWithHD=true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" style="display: inline; margin: 0 auto; overflow:hidden;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    <div style=
    "overflow: auto; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left:0; background-color: white; width:80%; height: 80%;">
    test page 1
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: in the style for your iframe remove what you have and add this --- position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; -- and remove this also -- height="100%" width="100%"

Comment: @Tasos no that didn't work, i think i would normally work but it seems the video is only able to resize and maintain its proportions. ie. no stretching.

Comment: can do a demo to check on codepen -- http://codepen.io/

Comment: @Tasos yes, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/7nvhscru/                the video doesn't play on jsfiddle but that's not a problem.

Comment: If you put the link of the video on  chrome browser and inspect it you will see it uses flash player to play it. On IE i don't use flash and inspecting it it uses an inbuild web player with a css class called (viewer__player) for the size, changing the css values gets you full screen -- check the img here --http://s2.postimg.org/hvnhzio2x/Capture.png -- however changing that css within an iframe for this class with code or css (as far as i know) is impossible, but check the net for a solution -- check this codepen with flash disabled --  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbmgyN  -- you maybe stuck

Comment: @Tasos thank you. that technique seems to be working